# API Gateway - CORS error with query string

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a GET request through API gateway that works when I test within the API Gateway console, so it seems my Lambda function is okay.

All my other methods and resources are working within the API, so I'm wondering if the query string parameter is causing the CORS issue. I've [enabled CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) for the GET method via the API Gateway console. Am I barking up the wrong tree to think it's the query string? What other areas should I look into to resolve the CORS error? Enabling CORS has resolved the issue before. The error is:

```
Access to fetch at 'myAPIURL' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The API call is as follows in my frontend:

```
fetchInvoices(strParam){
    const returnedData = null;
    const url = invokeURL + encodeURIComponent("invoicess?invYear=" + strParam);
    fetch(url, { headers: { "Authorization": token } })
        .then(response => { 
        return response.json() 
    })
    .then(jsonData => {
        returnedData = jsonData;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
    return returnedData
}
```

**EDIT**: I tested the API call without a query string parameter since it's optional and the CORS error went away. So is it something with the URL changing and the OPTIONS not being checked first in preflight?

Comment: No, typically the query string parameter isn't responsible for your preflight request failing. The error message says the `OPTIONS` request doesn't have an OK (ie 200-299) status ...

Comment: Your request is not [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests). So it triggers a cors preflight request (OPTIONS) which you need to configure your server to handle.  Adding authorization headers would make an otherwise simple request need a preflight check.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue. It occurs when you try to fetch resources from a different domain, protocol, or port than your current domain.

To fix this issue, you need to handle it from the backend by adding the appropriate CORS headers to the response. If you are using Express.js, you can use the cors package to allow specific origins.

However, if you don't have control over the API server, you can create a server-side proxy that will add the necessary headers for you.

Here's a simple example of how you can do this using express and http-proxy-middleware in Node.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ 
  target: 'http://myAPIURL', // original api url
  changeOrigin: true,
  onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
    proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  }
}));

app.listen(8080);
```

This will start a server on localhost:8080, and when you fetch from localhost:8080/api, it will proxy your request to http://myAPIURL, and add the necessary CORS headers to the response.

Now you can change your fetch url in your client side code:

```
fetchInvoices(strParam){
    const returnedData = null;
    const url = '/api' + encodeURIComponent("invoicess?invYear=" + strParam);
    fetch(url, { headers: { "Authorization": token } })
        .then(response => { 
        return response.json() 
    })
    .then(jsonData => {
        returnedData = jsonData;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
    return returnedData }
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question, but not including the string query in the path resolves the issue. My other methods require authorization and I didn't have to do anything beyond enable CORS - so trying to fix preflight with a different path

Comment: Just a reminder: [LLM (ChatGPT) content is disallowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)